# In Neo4j,Can a property of a node be a variable?

Tags: neo4j

In Neo4j,Can a property of a node be a variable? Can a change in the properties of one node be related to another node?
Thank U for help

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would like to do?

Comment: Let me give you an example to illustrate my problem. For example, I built a knowledge graph with parent nodes of "cooling and ventilation" and child nodes of "t1" and "t2". The parent node attributes are t2-t1 >. 6 ". So, can t2 and t1 in the parent node attribute be variables, which can be judged to be greater than 6 based on real-time input?

Answer (score 0):

No. The property is static when you assign a value into it. However, you can create a trigger which is very similar to most Relationnal Databaseas like Oracle. Here is the documentation about it.

```
 https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/background-operations/triggers/
```

Let say, you have a node Person and property surname. If you update the surname of a person, then you can change the surname of the children of this person using a trigger. Thus, when you update on Person.surname, it will automatically execute a cypher query to update the children.

```
 MATCH (d:Person {name:'Daniel'})
 SET d.surname = 'William'

 Will add/update other Person who are child(ren) of Daniel William.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, my problem may not be described clearly, so it is not what I need. Let me give you an example to illustrate my problem. For example, I built a knowledge graph with parent nodes of "cooling and ventilation" and child nodes of "t1" and "t2". The parent node attributes are t2-t1 > 6 ". So, can t2 and t1 in the parent node attribute be variables, which can be judged to be greater than 6 based on real-time input?

Comment: No. It cannot be done, not in NEO4J.

Comment: I'm still not exactly sure what you are trying to do. Is this a temporal analysis where you are measuring temperature in real time and then performing some sort of analysis or adjustment in the HVAC? Maybe this is useful? https://neo4j.com/labs/kafka/ 

It would help if you would describe the total scenario. If it's real time, why do you want to change properties of previous measurement (parent nodes) instead of sequentially adding nodes and processing the input data?